# How do a show an image on a HTML Email that will be sent to the customer

Tags: email, html

How do I add the src after I load the image I want displayed in the HTML Email I am creating?

I found the help that says upload the image to the document folder. It shows the example

```
<img src =" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt= "company Logo"
height = :64" width ="64"
```

I would think the src would display the image? Do I place

```
<img src =" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt= "company Logo"
height = :64" width ="64"
```

in the spot of the image?

I found this

```
<img src=”
https://dreamsxxxx--c.na10.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015F0000005PG3K&oid=00DF0000000gGXXx&lastMod=1443907446000”
height="90" width="600"/> <br/><br/>
```

https://dreamsxxxx--c.na10.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015F0000005PGXXoid=00DF0000000gXXx&lastMod=1443907446000

shows the image; but the above does not display the image in the email.

Comment: did u mark the image as externally available ?

Comment: Yes. The image is marked as externally available. When I send the email I have to lick on the link to see the image. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.